# Como puedo mejorar esta consulta a la base de datos de wordpress para generar los filtros de manera automática?

Tags: wordpress, filtros-css

la pregunta que tengo es como se podría mejorar la consulta a la base de datos, para que los filtros puedan generarse de manera automática, de la manera que lo estoy haciendo actualmente es primero obteniendo todos los productos de una categoría en particular y generando los atributos con sus valores para colocarlos en el filtro, pero se que si se llega a tener una cantidad muy alta de productos esta consulta puede ser muy ineficiente, entonces que me aconsejan para mejorar mi código, recuerden que actualmente si me esta funcionando bien, solo quiero mejorarlo para consultas mas grandes futuras.

```
<?php
get_header();

$category_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => $category_slug,
    'tax_query' => array()
);

$args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';

if (isset($_GET['min_price']) && is_numeric($_GET['min_price'])) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => $_GET['min_price'],
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    );
}

if (isset($_GET['max_price']) && is_numeric($_GET['max_price'])) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => $_GET['max_price'],
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    );
}

$attribute_slugs = array('pa_marca', 'pa_pais');

foreach ($attribute_slugs as $attribute_slug) {
    $filter_key = $attribute_slug . '_filter';
    if (isset($_GET[$filter_key]) && !empty($_GET[$filter_key])) {
        $term_ids = array_map('intval', $_GET[$filter_key]);
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $attribute_slug,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $term_ids,
            'operator' => 'IN', 
        );
    }
}

$products = new WP_Query($args);

$all_terms = array();

foreach ($attribute_slugs as $attribute_slug) {
    $all_terms[$attribute_slug] = array();
}

$lowest_price = PHP_INT_MAX;
$highest_price = 0;

if ($products->have_posts()) {
    while ($products->have_posts()) {
        $products->the_post();
        $product_id = get_the_ID();
        
        $product_price = floatval(get_post_meta($product_id, '_price', true));
        $lowest_price = min($lowest_price, $product_price);
        $highest_price = max($highest_price, $product_price);

        foreach ($attribute_slugs as $attribute_slug) {
            $product_terms = get_the_terms($product_id, $attribute_slug);

            if ($product_terms && !is_wp_error($product_terms)) {
                foreach ($product_terms as $term) {
                    $all_terms[$attribute_slug][$term->term_id] = $term->name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $products->rewind_posts();
}
wp_reset_postdata();

$args['posts_per_page'] = 20;

?>

<main class="container tienda-con-filtros">
<div class="menu-de-categorias" id="menu-de-categorias">
        <div class="cerrar">
           <button class="cerrar-menu-categorias" id="cerrar-menu-categorias"><span class="dashicons dashicons-no"></span></button>
        </div>
        <h4>Categorias</h4>
    <?php echo obtener_categorias_y_subcategorias();?>
</div>
<div class="filtros">
    <h4>Filtros</h4>
    <form id="filtros-principales" method="get">
        <div>
            <h5>Filtrar por rango de precios:</h5>
            <div>
                Precio mínimo: <input type="number" step="0.01" name="min_price" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['min_price']) ? esc_attr($_GET['min_price']) : $lowest_price; ?>">
                Precio máximo: <input type="number" step="0.01" name="max_price" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['max_price']) ? esc_attr($_GET['max_price']) : $highest_price; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        // 3. Generar la UI para cada filtro
        foreach ($all_terms as $attribute_slug => $terms) {
            if (!empty($terms)) {
                $filter_name = $attribute_slug . '_filter';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<h5>Filtrar por ' . ucfirst(str_replace('pa_', '', $attribute_slug)) . ':</h5><div>';
                
                foreach ($terms as $term_id => $term_name) {
                    $checked = isset($_GET[$filter_name]) && in_array($term_id, $_GET[$filter_name]) ? 'checked' : '';
                    echo '<label>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $filter_name . '[]" value="' . esc_attr($term_id) . '" ' . $checked . '> ' . esc_html($term_name);
                    echo '</label><br>';
                }
                
                echo '</div></div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
            <input id="enviar-filtros" type="submit" value="Filtrar">
            <input id="limpiar-filtros" type="reset" value="Limpiar" onclick="window.location.href=window.location.href.split('?')[0];">
    </form>
</div>

   <div class="contenedor-de-productos-con-filtros">
   <?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>

        <?php if ($products->have_posts()) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php single_term_title(); ?> <!-- Esto mostrará el nombre de la categoría -->
                </h1>
            </header>

            <ul class="products">
                <?php while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php wc_get_template_part('content', 'product'); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            
            <?php woocommerce_pagination(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p>No se encontraron productos para esta categoría.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
   
</main>

<?php 

get_footer();?>
```